# What is CLI server?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I am using getallheaders() php global function to get all the headers of the current request.
In php manual for it says that it is a alias of the apache_request_headers and it becomes available in CLI server. what is meant by CLI server?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 5.4.0, the PHP [command line interpreter (CLI)](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.introduction.php) also works as a [built-in webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php).

The [command line options](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) needed to start the CLI as web server are:

```
-S <addr>:<port> Run with built-in web server.
-t <docroot>     Specify document root <docroot> for built-in web server.
```

The function [`getallheaders()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php) apparently was not implemented in the built-in webserver from the beginning, it was added on version 5.5.7

Answer (score 0):

With the [php's bug #66606](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66606), the php's built-in web server stores the `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` header values in `HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE` and `HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH` fields.

You can get these values depending on the value of PHP_SAPI:

```
if ('cli-server' === PHP_SAPI) {
    if (array_key_exists('HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH', $_SERVER)) {
         $content_length = $_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH'];
    }
    if (array_key_exists('HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE', $_SERVER)) {
        $contentType = $_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE'];
    }
}
```